# Angular NGXS Observable collection

Tags: angular, redux

i am porting my vanialla angular project to redux with ngxs.

So i have a list of items in my state which will be rendered in a ui Form which is somewhat expensive. In my non redux project this component observes changes to this list with IterableDiffers. And only changed items are converted to controls and reflected in the ui.

In redux this list would be part of the state which means it will be immutable so i cannot observe it anymore. Do you folks have any idea how to tackle this issue?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Immutability doesn't mean inability to observe. You can use `Select` https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select#select-decorators

Comment: @Sergey I perfectly understand that i can observe slices of the store. So my reffered collection is an array as part of the state. For now this array is observed by IterableDiffers and I can track changes made to it. With NGXS is end up with getting a new list an I have no clue what changed. Of course I can now go and compare the new list to the old but i don't know whether this is the desired way.